# Mountain bike tires

Tags: replacement

Would be safe to drive my mountain bike with little cracks on the tire?please help I will used it for university. Do I have to replace my tires?
[image][image]

Comment: It's probably safe, though it's hard to tell how badly cracked it is and how much "life" is left in the tire.  More worrisome would be cracks in the sides of the tire.

Comment: In one crack the threads are visible. What worries me are the fine cracks on the surfaces between the blocks that indicate a rather aged tyre. Replace to avoid a failure while on your commute.

Comment: If you're going to commute to, from, and around campus, a fresh set of slick tires would ride better (faster + better cornering) and provide some peace of mind

Answer (score 3):

Looks harmless.

A tire gets its strength from the cloth casing (“carcass”). The rubber tread is mainly there for grip and durability. It also provides some puncture protection.

Cracks in the rubber usually form due to age (+exposure to the elements) and/or insufficient tire pressure.

My main concern would be that if the rubber is old and hard your grip will be worse, especially on wet surfaces.